Trouble with USB-disks
I've had Ubuntu for many years now and have consumed some 4-5 servers. All of them had external USB-disks and I've only experienced troubles when a HDD crashed hardware wise, never spontaneous degragings.
I've recently installed a new HP small factor server, it has four USB 3.1 ports. OS is Ubuntu 24.04.1. There's four 16 TB HDD USB-drives attached, Raid1 md0 = 16 + 16 TB and md1 = 16 + 16 TB and Raid0 md2 = md0 + md1, gives approx 32 TB. The disks are not brand new, has been working for about 1,5 year on the old Backup-server.
The problem is that md0 or md1 sdN-disks fails, the log says only "Fail". Syslog: md/raid1:md1: Disk failure on sdf1, disabling device.
It could by any of these four disks. This server is Ubuntu 24.04.1, my other four Ubuntu servers runs 22.04.4.
This is a bit strange, if only one disk failed I could suspect the USB-port or the hard drive, but this isn't the case, all fails randomly. (Action: Power off the drive, power on and resyncing the Raid).
This did not happen with the old server and with these same disks, nor other servers with Ubuntu 22.04.5.
Could it be a Ubuntu problem with version 24.04.1, just a humble question?
Or could it more likely be a server hardware issue? Server: 2 x USB are 3.2 Gen 2 (3.1 Gen 2) - 2 x USB are 3.2 Gen 1 (3.1 Gen 1).
HDD: USB are 3.0. Smart status says 6Gb/s SATA throughput status. One partition/disk. Linux ext4 formatted.
